# Find an exact UIImageView on a cell in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

in my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
//...do cell setup etc.

            UIImage *iconthumbNail = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
        UIImageView * iconimgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(265, 34, 25, 25)];
        [iconimgView setImage:iconthumbNail];
        //imgView.image = thumbNail;
        [cell addSubview:iconimgView];
        [iconimgView release];
      // add a few more UIImageViews to the cell
    }
```

So then in my

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

UITableViewCell * theCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    for (UIView * b in cell.subviews)
{
    if ([b isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
    {
        // how do I check that its 'iconImgView' so that I can change it?
    }
}
```

So I add an UIImageView in my cellForRowAtIndexPath, then when that table cell is selected I want to change one of the images in the cell, 'iconImgView' but how do I identify this UIImageView from the other UIImageViews present in that cell?

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using that approach, I would assign a tag to the `UIImageView` you are looking for.

```
iconimgView.tag = 1;
```

Then in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, use this:

```
UIImageView *iconimgView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
```

If you still want to do it your way, you can do like this:

```
if ([b isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
    UIImageView *myView = (UIImageView *)b;
    if ([b.image isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName"]]) {
        // Do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mart! I'm guessing the 'tag' method would be most efficent?

Comment: What is the value of tag property by default? If its 0, then it can create trouble in case of 0th cell.

Comment: Why would that cause trouble? The tag for the ImageView is the same for all cells. And yes, the tagmethod if the most efficient.

Comment: if the cell have more than one UIViews and all the default 0 tag. So in case of 0 it may return the wrong UIView.

Comment: What case of 0? You assign the tag yourself. So just don't set the tag to zero. The meaning with tags is to keep track of the object.

Comment: I guess now the point is clear not to start tagging with 0. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

If your only goal is to change the image of the selected cell, this can be done more efficiently. All you have to do is read/write to the cells imageView property.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *theCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [[theCell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.jpg"]];//altering the existing image
    UIImageView *myImageView = theCell.imageView;//read the image property of the cell
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```